# Latching relay circuit design

Tags: relay

[image]

I am designing a circuit to control a latching relay through an MCU. I got this circuit from one of the application notes.

I want to run my [K153A-D012P-1BT](https://kgtechnologies.net/productdetails/k153--90a-high-power-latching-relay) latching relay. What are the changes I need to do in the circuit to run my relay?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your relay is a dual coil design with a common negative terminal, 12V operated, with 48 ohm per coil (250 mA), according to the datasheet. This means you do not need a "push-pull" circuit to drive a single coil in both directions as in your example schematic.

Possible solution with BJT's:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fBkksF.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Thank you. the circuit is working fine

Comment: @vinayakpotadar There is another nice way to say "thank you" on this site..

Comment: @Jens Thank you