# Optocoupler as UART communication

Tags: opto-isolator

I am using the LTV-816S optocoupler for isolated data communication. When I give 4V supply to U1.1 then I get 3.3 at RX. but when I give a signal (4V) at U1.2 pin then at Rx I should get 0 but I am getting 1.2V approx. what could be the reason for that? I am missing something in the circuit.[R1=2.7K, R2=1k].

[image]

Comment: your schematic diagram is upside down... please follow schematic drawing convention ... Vcc at top, gnd at bottom

Comment: The device chosen is not a logic input/output device and your expectations as such are not going to be met it seems. Have you ever thought about reviewing your previous questions for answers that can be formally accepted as a means of showing that you respect the help from people answering? I'm not guaranteeing better help but is it worth the risk?

Comment: yes. I do respect the people who answer my question. @Andyaka

Comment: I hope to see that demonstrated in the answers you have formally accepted.

Comment: Thanks @Andyaka

Comment: https://www.ti.com/lit/ml/sllt217/sllt217.pdf?ts=1668588146502&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F

Comment: @jsotola, yes I will update the schematic. may I know why it is behaving abnormal and giving 1.2V ?

Comment: @AKR thank you but I wan to use this one. Is my circuit correct ?

Comment: Another "hint" regarding the netiquette https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/630379/latching-relay-circuit-design#comment1667305_630388

Comment: I changed my R1 value to 330E and when I connect it I get 0.120V at Rx pin. Anyone please correct me if I am doing anything wrong in the Circuit

Comment: UART signals are idle high. A low level at pin U1.2 should turn on the LED and RX follows with a low level.

Comment: @vinayakpotadar May I please know why the obsession with optos, GI usually has been the goal for the industry. Would like to know about the use case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is \$V_{CE}\$ isn't saturated with \$R_1 = 2.7kΩ\$ and \$R_2 = 1kΩ\$.

\$I_F = (4V - V_F) / R_1 = 2.8V/R_1 = 2.8V/2.7kΩ = 1.04mA\$

\$I_C = 3.3V/R_2 = 3.3mA\$

You have to operate the photocoupler in the range where the transistor is saturated (where the curve is flat).

[image]
<sup>Source: [Datasheet](https://www.mouser.ch/datasheet/2/239/LTV_8X6_series-2887056.pdf)</sup>

In the comments you wrote you changed \$R_1\$ to \$330Ω\$

\$I_F = 2.8V/330Ω = 8.48mA\$

And you measured \$V_{CE} = 0.12V\$, which is as good a value as you can expect.

[image]

This isn't an ideal transistor, so you'll never get \$V_{CE(sat)} = 0V\$.